# System.config map for @angular modules from a single .js file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bundle, systemjs

I am currently developing an Angular 2 application, where the requirement is to put all the resulting javascript files to a single .js file (Namely: output.js)

Now, I 've to add map configuration in System.config.js.

There we usually give the location of the folders for respective modules.

Eg.)

```js
var map = {
  '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular'
};
```

But now that I have everything in a single Javascript file, how do I map those entries?

The problem I am facing because of this is, whenever I try loading the html, it looks for @angular module internally and fails as the path is different.

My HTML looks like this,

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="output.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<test-app>Loading...</test-app>
<script>
  System.import('runtime/main').then(null, function(err) {console.log(err)});
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

My System.config.js looks like this,

```js
(function (global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
   var map = {
        'app': 'dist', // 'dist',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        'ng2-img-cropper': 'ng2-img-cropper'
    };
  
  //The above is where I face problems. Since it points to node_modules, I want this to be changed

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': {main: 'newAgain.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
    };

    var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'};
    });

    var config = {
        packages: packages
    };

    // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
    if (global.filterSystemConfig) {
        global.filterSystemConfig(config);
    }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Summary:

1. I have a html file
2. I have a single .js file (output.js) that includes the scripts from all dependencies and also the project specific js. (Like angular, systemjs, rxjs, ....)

Requirement:

1. Link/Map modules properly in the system.config.js configuration.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I was able to get an answer to the above solution. 
I have actually made that as a git repository.

If anybody is looking for the answer for these kinds of problems.
[Github - angular2-bundle-all-single-script](https://github.com/arunkumars08/angular2-bundle-all-single-script)